# Find element by the value attribute using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I`m trying to find a specific element in the web page. It has to be by a specific number inside the text in value...In this case, I need to find the element by the number 565657 (see outer HTML below)

I've tried via xpath: `("//*[contains(text(),'565657')]")` and also `("//input[@value='565657']")` but it did not work.

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

The original XPATH when you copy from the element on the web page is just ' //*[@id="checkbox15"]' and I need to find a way to look for the number I mentioned below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To locate the element through the value attribute i.e. ***565657*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value*='565657']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@vlaue, '565657')]")
  ```

To locate ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value*='565657']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@vlaue, '565657')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```